# Access Applications directory with Terminal in Recovery Mode

Tags: terminal, applications, library, mamp

I hope someone can help.

I'm trying to access my Appplications directory in Recovery Mode of my iMac with Terminal. I want to copy a folder to an external hard drive. After updating to Big Sur, my iMac won't start and so I need some files to save. The path I want to access is `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`.

When I type `ls /Applications/MAMP`: it says that there is no such file or directory.
When I type `ls /Applications`: Safari.app and Utilities appear.

When I type `ls /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/users/"username"/Applications` .localized appears.

Is there another command I have to use? Is it even possible to get into the application folder?

By the way: I already copied the whole Library folder... maybe it's possible to override the MAMP-files? Or do I need another backup of the htdocs-folder?

Edit: This is the result of `diskutil list internal`

[image]

Comment: Have you try `ls /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/System/Applications`  ?

Comment: It says "No such file or directory", too.

Comment: Can you give the results of command `diskutil list internal` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in **macOS Recovery** from **macOS Big Sur**, in **Terminal**, the location of the **MAMP** installed **htdocs** *folder* is, e.g.,:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Applications/MAMP/htdocs
```

You can also use the `find` *command* to locate it, e.g.,:

```
find /Volumes -type d -name 'htdocs' 2>/dev/null
```

The output of that `find` *command* would be, e.g.,:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Applications/MAMP/htdocs
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs
```

The one with `Macintosh HD - Data` is the one you want.

---

When in **macOS Recovery**, using **Terminal** can be a bit difficult. I find using **Disk Utility** to backup select *folders*, saving the **DMG Image** to an external drive, is much easier, albeit even if copying a bit more than needed.

**Disk Utility** > **File** > **New Image** > **Image from Folder…**

[image]

<sup>Note that there is no external drive attached and the picture is just to show ease of access to the *file system* compared to using **Terminal**.</sup>

Comment: You are my hero!!! I solved it... The right path in Terminal is `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Previous System/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`
Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll try the Disk Utility method, too. Sounds easier and probably would have saved a lot of time. Thanks a lot for your support!